# Meteor listing all users in Meteor.users

Tags: meteor

I am trying to manage my Meteor app users data (role, profile data...etc) which are saved in the Meteor.users collection but can't seem to find how to list all available users accounts (their ID, email...etc) while logged in as user, so I was wondering if someone can please help me by telling me how to do so? Any example will be highly appreciated.

I've tried using Meteor.users.find(), Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}}); but with no luck even though there are 3 users already defined in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor.users.find() returns all users, did you remember about publishing/subscribing this collection?

Comment: autopublish is still enabled, so didn't have to do any pub/sub. Tried Meteor.users.find() but no data returned

Comment: Well it has to, try console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch());

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it :)